# Unable to get property 'subject' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to make a little app in ionic, but it gave me that error when i call the `$scope.saveClass()` function from the UI.

*Unable to get property 'subject' of undefined or null reference*

I don't understand because he doesn't work. Premise: i'm new to ionic/angularjs developing.

I thank you in advance for helping

code (www/js/controllers.js)

```
 angular.module('starter.controllers')
    .service("DB", function() {
        this.classDB = new PouchDB("classesDB");
    })

    .controller("AddClassCtrl", function ($scope, DB) {
        $scope.saveClass = function () {
            var newclass = {
                "_id": $scope.class.subject,
                "subject": $scope.class.subject,
               "room": $scope.class.room
            }

            DB.classDB.put(newclass);

            window.location.href = '#app/schedule'
        };
    })
```

Code (add-class.html)

```
<ion-content controller="AddClassCrtl">
   <div class="list">

   <!--Select the subject-->
   <label class="item item-input item-select">
      <div class="input-label">
         Subject
      </div>
      <button class="button button-block button-positive overflowShow"> Add a subjects </button>
      <select class="item-input" ng-model="class.subject" ng-selected="class.subject">
         <option ng-repeat="subject in subjects">{{subject}}</option>
      </select>
   </label>
   <!--Insert the room number-->
   <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Room" ng-model="class.room" ng-text-change="class.room">
   </label>
   <div class="item">
      <button ng-click="discardClass()" class="button button-block">Discard</button>
      <button ng-click="saveClass()" class="button button-block">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because you didn't initialize $scope.class variable and in fact, when you try to access $scope.class.subject, $scope.class is undefined. Add this code at the beginning of your controller:

```
$scope.class = {};
```